# HDFS Change Rate

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I have a cluster of several nodes running HDFS and YARN, managed by CDH, with several services deployed. Is there a way to determine the aggregate rate at which data is changed across the whole cluster?

Comment: (size at time1 - size at time2) / (time1 - time2) ??

Comment: Unfortunately, since a lot of data may be overwritten, size of the overall filesystem won't do it. I'll update the original question: I probably should've said "changed" instead of "added".